# Spring Integration and SOAP 1.2: setting SOAPAction

Tags: java, soap, spring-integration, spring-ws

I am developing a client app with Spring Integration that needs to call a SOAP 1.2 service.  If I set the SOAPAction with int-ws:header-enricher:

```
<int-ws:header-enricher >
    <int-ws:soap-action value="foo"/>
</int-ws:header-enricher>
```

I get a weird Content-Type header with the action on a separate line, preceded by a tab char:

```
>> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; [\r][\n]"
>> "[0x9]action="foo"[\r][\n]"
```

I tried calling SaajSoapMessage.setSoapAction() in WebServiceMessageCallback.doWithMessage() but the result is the same.  If I don't explicitly set the SOAPAction the Content-Type header is all on one line with no tab char, but the action is empty.

```
>> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=""[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: That’s really something weird. It definitely must be a separate header and its name should be `soapaction`: https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528

Comment: Well for SOAP 1.2 a separate soapaction header is not used, it is part of the Content-Type header.  So in my example it should be 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="foo"'.

Comment: Hm. How about to try to use Axiom instead of SAAJ: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e653 ?

Comment: That fixes it, thanks!  Using AxiomSoapMessageFactory sets the Content-Type header correctly for SOAP 1.2.

Comment: FWIW: The code that generates the newlines can be found in `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.ParameterList.toString(int)`, which is in turn used by `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.ContentType.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

I got used to for the `AxiomSoapMessageFactory` instead of the default `SaajSoapMessageFactory`. It always served me well for both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 and also provides enough help with the large and with the attachment messages.